# How to reduce Clickable area React Native, not increase

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried hitSlope but not working to reduce the clickable area. I want this because the transparent background is more than the image itself and I think it is causing more area to click, causing unnecessary clicks even not clicked on the image. I am attaching the image as well[The image is here. Please help me if I can modify the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ1zw.png)

I am trying to get 2 rows and 3 images in each row in react Native. Its taking my soul

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Pressable, Image, ScrollView, Alert } from "react-native";
import * as ScreenOrientation from "expo-screen-orientation";
const ImageComponent = ({ source }) => (
    <Pressable hitSlop={{bottom:-10}} onPress={() => Alert.alert("Image clicked!")}>
    <Image
        source={require("./resources/Freezer_11.png")}
        style={styles.image}
      />
    </Pressable>
);
const App = () => {
  async function changeScreenOrientation() {
    try {
      await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(
        ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE
      );
      console.log("Screen orientation locked successfully.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error locking screen orientation:", error);
    }
  }
  changeScreenOrientation();

  return (
    <ScrollView>
<View style={styles.scroll}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageComponent/>
      <Image
        source={require("./resources/Freezer_11.png")}
        style={styles.image}
      />
      <Image
        source={require("./resources/Freezer_11.png")}
        style={styles.image}
      />
      <Image
        source={require("./resources/Freezer_11.png")}
        style={styles.image}
      />
      <Image
        source={require("./resources/Freezer_11.png")}
        style={styles.image}
      />
      <Image
        source={require("./resources/Freezer_11.png")}
        style={styles.image}
      />
    </View>
    </View>
    </ScrollView>

  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scroll:{
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center",
  },
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: "#d9d9d9",
    width: "95%",
    height: "90%",
    borderRadius: 20,
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center",
    flexWrap:"wrap",
  },

  image:{
    width: "33%",
    height: "50%",
    aspectRatio:1,
    resizeMode:"contain",
  }
});

export default App;
```